# Salesforce ERP Integrations

Tags: integration, data, setup

I am curious how people manage two way data. Let's take a very basic example. If i use the vanilla setup i import my accounts into salesforce. Now i have to maintain accounts (additions, deletions, updates) in both are ERP and now in salesforce is that correct?

What options do i have here to make this seamless.

- Manual daily imports (this is not ideal)
- Having the accounts only in the erp system but exposed to salesforce using a rest api? (this would be fantastic)
- Daily automated batch updates say at 1:00 am that keeps
  the two systems in check.
- An export from salesforce, then a compare
  to erp, then apply changes to both systems (this is complex and
  kludgy).

Right now all of our data is in a dated legacy system but i have written an abstraction layer where i can offer the data through rest or as records in a postgres database. I really have infinite flexibility on this side of the communications.

I am looking for the path of least resistance between daily batch updates and just shared data(preferably). How are you setting up and managing this at your sites?

Answer (score 1):

The organization I currently am consulting at seems to like Salesforce Connect external objects. They update in real-time from your data source, so you don't have to worry about synchronization between the two. If your data is accessible via OData and you can use Basic or OAuth to authenticate, then this may be a viable solution for you.

I should note that you cannot EDIT the data in Salesforce connect objects.
EDIT: It looks like one of the new features in Winter '16 is the ability to edit external objects: https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter16/release-notes/rn_forcecom_external_data_writeable_objects.htm

You can learn more about Salesforce Connect here: http://www.slideshare.net/developerforce/df13-using-external-objects-for-integration-mt

Trailhead even has a unit on Salesforce Connect: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/lightning_connect/lightning_connect_setup

Comment: First link throws a 404 on linkedin.

Comment: Are you logged in to LinkedIn? I have no problem with it.